# Multiple rows are not showing when we convert the table data into XML in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008-r2, sql-server-2012

I have two table as given below.

`OrderHeader`:

```
PKOrderHeader CustomerCode DocumentRef SiteCode
1         JOE          TEST1       TH
2         POL          TEST2       CO
3             GEO          TEST3       KH
```

`OrderDetails`:

```
FKOrderHeader   ProductCode RotationLineNo
1       PRD1        1
1                         PRD2        2
2               PRD3        2
3               PRD4        3
```

I need to get the XML string as below after converting the table data as XML string

```
<ORDERS>
   <SO>
       <HD>
           <PKOrderHeader>1</PKOrderHeader>
           <CustomerCode>JOE</CustomerCode>
       </HD>
       <HO>
           <DocumentRef>TEST1</DocumentRef>
           <SiteCode>TH</SiteCode>
       </HO>
       <LO>
           <FKOrderHeader>1</FKOrderHeader>
           <ProductCode>PRD1</ProductCode>
           <RotationLineNo>1</RotationLineNo>
       </LO>
       <LO>
           <FKOrderHeader>1</FKOrderHeader>
           <ProductCode>PRD2</ProductCode>
           <RotationLineNo>2</RotationLineNo>
       </LO>
  </SO>
  <SO>
     <HD>
           <PKOrderHeader>2</PKOrderHeader>
           <CustomerCode>POL</CustomerCode>
       </HD>
       <HO>
           <DocumentRef>TEST2</DocumentRef>
           <SiteCode>CO</SiteCode>
       </HO>
       <LO>
           <FKOrderHeader>2</FKOrderHeader>
           <ProductCode>PRD2</ProductCode>
           <RotationLineNo>2</RotationLineNo>
       </LO>       
  </SO>
  <SO>
     <HD>
           <PKOrderHeader>3</PKOrderHeader>
           <CustomerCode>GOE</CustomerCode>
       </HD>
       <HO>
           <DocumentRef>TEST3</DocumentRef>
           <SiteCode>KH</SiteCode>
       </HO>
       <LO>
           <FKOrderHeader>3</FKOrderHeader>
           <ProductCode>PRD3</ProductCode>
           <RotationLineNo>3</RotationLineNo>
       </LO>  
   </SO>
</ORDERS>
```

The query that I used to generate the XML string is as given

```
 SELECT
    (SELECT PKOrderHeader, CustomerCode FROM #OrderHeader FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS HD,
    (SELECT DocumentRef, SiteCode FROM #OrderHeader FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS HO,      
    (SELECT FKOrderHeader, ProductCode, RotationLineNo FROM #OrderDetail FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE) AS LO
FOR XML PATH('SO'), ROOT('ORDERS')
```

But when I generated the XML string I am getting only the single rows data as XML string as liken given below. Also the LO section is also not showing the multiple rows.

```
<ORDERS>
   <SO>
       <HD>
           <PKOrderHeader>1</PKOrderHeader>
           <CustomerCode>JOE</CustomerCode>
       </HD>
       <HO>
           <DocumentRef>TEST1</DocumentRef>
           <SiteCode>TH</SiteCode>
       </HO>
       <LO>
           <FKOrderHeader>1</FKOrderHeader>
           <ProductCode>PRD1</ProductCode>
           <RotationLineNo>1</RotationLineNo>
       </LO>
   </SO>
</ORDERS>
```

So can anyone help me to get multiple row data as XML string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve what you need using the following query:

```
select
    (select PKOrderHeader, CustomerCode for xml path('HD'), type),
    (select DocumentRef, SiteCode for xml path('HO'), type),
    (
        select FKOrderHeader, ProductCode, RotationLineNo
        from #OrderDetails od
        where od.FKOrderHeader = oh.PKOrderHeader
        for xml path('LO'), type
    )
from #OrderHeader oh
for xml path('SO'), root('ORDERS')
```

Comment: Thank you ,it seems to be wroking